# IntegrityError when inserting data in an association table using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to insert the role data in this association table:

```
class Association(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'associations'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('teams.id'), primary_key=True)
    role = db.Column(db.String)
    user = db.relationship("User", back_populates="teams")
    team = db.relationship("Team", back_populates="users")
```

It's linked to 2 other tables:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String)
    username = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String)
    teams = db.relationship("Association", back_populates="user")

class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
    player = db.Column(db.String)
    users = db.relationship("Association", back_populates="team")
```

However, when I try to insert the role in the association table:

```
t = Team.query.filter_by(id=team_name1_id).first()
a = Association(role=form.role.data)
a.user = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
t.users.append(a)
db.session.add(t)
db.session.commit()
```

I get this error:

> IntegrityError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush;
>   consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring
>   prematurely) (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   association.team_id [SQL: u'INSERT INTO association (user_id, role)
>   VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: (1, u'point guard')]

Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922210/why-does-a-query-invoke-a-auto-flush-in-sqlalchemy

Answer (score 9):

The line that causes the [autoflush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.params.autoflush) is

```
t.users.append(a)
```

You've not defined your [relationship loading strategies](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#relationship-loading-techniques), so they default to [`"select"`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#configuring-loader-strategies-at-mapping-time). Since you're accessing the `Team.users` relationship attribute for the first time, it will emit a SELECT in order to fetch the related objects.

You've also made changes to the session indirectly in

```
a.user = User.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()
```

which due to [save-update cascade](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/cascades.html#save-update), on by default, places the new `Association` instance to the session as well.

In order to keep the DB's and session's state consistent SQLAlchemy has to [flush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#flushing) your changes to the DB before the query is emitted, and so the half initialized `Association` is sent to the DB before being associated with the `Team` instance.

Possible solutions:

1. [Temporarily disable the autoflush feature](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.no_autoflush) for that particular append because you know you're adding a new `Association`:

   ```
   with db.session.no_autoflush:
       t.users.append(a)
   ```

   The SELECT will still be emitted, though.
2. Reverse the operation. Instead of appending the `Association` instance to the `Team.users` collection, assign the `Team` to the `Association.team`:

   ```
   # Instead of t.users.append(a):
   a.team = t  # Mr.
   ```
3. A less obvious solution is to [eager load](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#joined-eager-loading) the contents of the relationship when you fetch the `Team` instance, so that no SELECT is necessary:

   ```
   t = db.session.query(Team).options(db.joinedload(Team.users)).first()
   ```

   or not load them at all using the [`db.noload(Team.users)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.noload) option.

Note that

```
db.session.add(t)
```

is redundant. The fetched `Team` instance is already in the session – otherwise the lazy load of `Team.users` [could not have proceeded](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/errors.html#parent-instance-x-is-not-bound-to-a-session-lazy-load-deferred-load-refresh-etc-operation-cannot-proceed) in the first place.

Comment: I substituted "t.users.append(a)" with "a.team = t" and it worked perfectly... thank you!