# How to append an object in a many-many-to-many relationship via association object in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a User class, Tag Class and UserTag class which is the the association object. UserTag is an association object because i need it to store an extra column tag_type.
Below are the three classes that represents my tables:

```
class UserTag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'usertag'
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
    tag_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id'), primary_key=True)
    tag_type = db.Column(db.Boolean, unique=False, nullable=False)
    tag = db.relationship('Tag', back_populates='users')
    user = db.relationship('User', back_populates='tags')


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    bio = db.Column(db.String(160), unique=False, nullable=False)
    image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpeg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    tags = db.relationship('UserTag', back_populates='user')


class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename = 'tag'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tagname = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    users = db.relationship('UserTag', back_populates='tag')
```

I created them according to the documentation here:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object

I was able to create instances and form associations at first using the python shell by running:

```
userdemo = User(username='demo', email='demo@email.com', bio='I love python!', password='password')

tpython = Tag(tagname='python')

assoc = UserTag(tag_type=True)

assoc.tag = tpython

userdemo.tags.append(assoc)
```

I was able to successfully add the data to the database session and commit the data. However on running the python shell a second time and while trying to add more tags and associate them with a user I got the following warning.

```
>AWarning: Column 'usertag.user_id' is marked as a member of the primary key for table 'usertag', but has no Python-side or server-side default generator indicated, nor does it indicate 'autoincrement=True' or 'nullable=True', and no explicit value is passed.  Primary key columns typically may not store NULL. Note that as of SQLAlchemy 1.1, 'autoincrement=True' must be indicated explicitly for composite (e.g. multicolumn) primary keys if AUTO_INCREMENT/SERIAL/IDENTITY behavior is expected for one of the columns in the primary key. CREATE TABLE statements are impacted by this change as well on most backends.
  util.warn(msg)
```

After the warning I tried to append the UserTag to user and received the following error

```
> raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (raised as a result of Query-invoked autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush is occurring prematurely)
(sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: usertag.user_id
[SQL: INSERT INTO usertag (tag_id, tag_type) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: (1, 1)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj) (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/7s2a)
```

Now I am unable to append UserTag associations to the tags column on User. I don't really understand what is happening.

Comment: Do I need to set the primary_key  to True for the two foreign keys? Users can have multiple tags and Tags can be displayed by many users. so in the foreign key table (association object) user 1 can have tag 1 and tag  2. User 2 can also have tag 1 and tag 2. If it is set to primary_key=True will that be possible? can we still store duplicate tag id for different users?

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled the autoflush feature as a solution to the error. More information regarding the error can be found here [IntegrityError when inserting data in an association table using SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48188660/integrityerror-when-inserting-data-in-an-association-table-using-sqlalchemy)